# What fraction of primes are $3 (mod 4)$?

Tags: number-theory, distribution-of-primes

As $n\rightarrow\infty$, we know that the fraction of primes that are $2 \hspace{1mm}(mod\hspace{1mm}4)$ tends to zero as two is the only prime with that property.

While I am aware that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4k+1$ and infinitely many of the form $4k+3$ what is the distribution like? As $n\rightarrow \infty$ do the number of $4k+1$ primes and $4k+3$ primes grow at different rates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Prime Number Theorem for arithmetic progressions states that
$$\pi(x;a,n)\sim\frac1{\phi(n)}\frac{x}{\ln x}$$
as $x\to\infty$. Here $a$ is coprime to $n$, and $\pi(x;a,n)$
is the number of primes $p$ with $p\le x$ and $p\equiv a\pmod n$.
Also $\phi$ denote's Euler's totient.
In particular,
$$\pi(x;1,4)\sim\pi(x;3,4)\sim\frac12\frac{x}{\ln x}\sim\frac{\pi(x)}2.$$

But there are more subtle aspects to this. Although $\pi(x;1,4)-\pi(x;3,4)$ is $o(x/\ln x)$ it appears to be more often negative than positive; this is [Chebsyshev's bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_bias).

Comment: I have seen one very nice article on this long time ago, but don't remember the correct link. The title was "prime number races" (2006) by Granville/Martin. Ah I had kept the reference : "The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 113, No. 1 (Jan., 2006), pp. 1-33" It's on jstor

Answer (score 2):

***No answer, but a nice reference***
There is a quite entertaining article by A.Granville and G. Martin, titled "prime numbers race" in the 2006-volume of MAA's series.

It starts:

> INTRODUCTION. There's nothing quite like a day at the races... The
>   quickening of the pulse as the starter's pistol sounds, the thrill
>   when your favorite contestant speeds out into the lead (or the
>   distress if another contestant dashes out ahead of yours), and the
>   accompanying fear (or hope) that the leader might change.  And what if
>   the race is a marathon? Maybe one of the contestants will be far
>   stronger than the others, taking the lead and running at the head of
>   the pack for the whole race. Or perhaps the race will be more
>   dramatic, with the lead changing again and again for as long as one
>   cares to watch.
>
> Our race involves the odd prime numbers, separated
>   into two teams depending on the remainder when they are divided by 4:
>   (table)
>
> In this Mod 4 Race, Team 3 contains the primes of the form 4n+3, and Team 1
>   contains the primes of the form 4n + 1.
>   The Mod 4 Race has just two contestants and is quite some marathon because it ***goes
>   on forever!*** From the data (...)

*(enhancement by me)*

> Theorem (J.E. Littlewood, 1914). There are arbitrarily large values of
>   x for which there are more primes of the form 4n + 1 up to x than
>   primes of the form 4n + 3. In fact, there are arbitrarily large values
>   of x for which (...)

See: "The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 113, No. 1 (Jan., 2006), pp. 1-33"
It's on jstor